# Capture Single Emoji using Regex

Tags: regex, unicode

Of all the Emojis present in a text, I want to capture Strawberry emoji ().

Using Google I narrowed down my expression from

```
(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])
```

to

```
(\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff])
```

This narrows my search to fewer emojis but still captures others as well:

I found out each emoji has its own range and Unicode, E.G Strawberry () has the range 6107-6108 and Unicode (U+1F353), Apple () has range 6086-6087 and Unicode (U+1F34E).

How do I narrow down my regex further, so that it captures the single Emoji while ignoring the rest?

Comment: What language? This seems extra important in this case.

Comment: For example, `\N{Strawberry}` works fine in python

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "range" here. Could you provide a bit more information about what you've been googling?

Answer (score 1):

A resource like [unicode-table.com](https://unicode-table.com/en/1F353/) will supply all the information you need about a code-point, including name, glyph representations, and most importantly encoding. For strawberry, you have the following:

> Name: Strawberry
> Glyph: 
> Code: `0x1F353`
> UTF-8: `\xF0 \x9F \x8D \x93`
> UTF-16(BE): `\uD83C \uDF53`
> UTF-32(BE): `\U0001F353`

How you represent your search string depends on the language/flavor of your regex. For example, regex101.com tends to have minimal support for Unicode, so you have two options:

1. Literal strawberry:

   `//`
2. UTF-16 (big endian):

   `/\uD83C\uDF53/`

A language like python has a lot more support you can use any of the options in the little table above with the appropriate escapes:

1. `'\N{Strawberry}'`
2. `'\U0001F353'`
3. `'\uD83C\uDF53'`
4. `''`

All of these are equivalent to the literal strawberry glyph: these escapes are parsed by the interpreter, not the regex engine.

The key is that Unicode is an extremely well documented resource. It may seem complicated, and often is, but you'll find that looking up the appropriate documentation is always easier than exhaustive guess-and-check in the long run.

I highly recommend reading [Python's Unicode HowTo](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html). It's not exhaustive, but is an excellent resource which will point you in all the right directions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is an intelligent way to find it but you already narrowed it down a lot. With trial and error I found the exact match :

```
\ud83c\udf53
```

See https://regex101.com/r/7psOg1/1

Edit : after some research, it seems you need a unicode to hex converter. There are a lot of them online. Just paste your emoji and the associated unicode will show. For example, for , you get d83eded0
which means `\ud83e\uded0` will match 
Note that you have to choose the unicode 16 encoding.

Comment: That's just the UTF-16BE representation. What are you narrowing down?

Comment: Well the question indicated \ud83c[\ud000-\udfff] matched the strawberry. So I searched from there. Your answer is a lot better though: The resource you provided makes it very easy to reconstruct the regex from the UTF-16BE encoding

Comment: Based on the terminology and attempts in the question I assumed the OP had no idea how to use Unicode and started from scratch. The whole narrowing down guess and check thing really just confused me.